# Using HandlerExceptionResolver for 404

Tags: java, exception, spring-mvc

I wanted to use **HandlerExceptionResolver** to handle exceptions related to request issues such as 404 and other error codes.  Tomcat seems to respond to these errors without looking at Spring.  Is there a way to make **HandlerExceptionResolver** respond to 404 errors.

I know that configuring `web.xml` and using `<error-page>` will work.  But is there a way to do this by registering the **HandlerExceptionResolver** or something similar to that using Spring MVC?

Comment: It depends how far the request is getting before the 404 is thrown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exceptions and HTTP Response error codes are two different things. Spring's `HandlerExceptionResolver` can be used to resolve exceptions but not error codes. `web.xml` is the best place to handle error codes.